# The performance difference between avg and max for mysql's json data type

Tags: mysql, json

everyone:

i am using the mysql 5.7, and want to test the performance of json data type.

I create table using follow sql:

```
CREATE TABLE pm_data_tab_json (
    oid     varchar(16)    NOT NULL
    time    datetime       NOT NULL
    vals    JSON           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`oid`,`time`) 
);
```

and i insert about ten millions of records into the table to test performance of mysql json process. the record format is as following:

20110200001 | 2015-06-30 23:50:00 | {"fs/0": 10, "fv/0": 5212600}

i used the following sql to get max fv/0 value every 3600 seconds:

```
select max( JSON_EXTRACT(vals, '$."fv/0"') ) AS val, max(time) AS valtime from pm_data_tab_json where oid='20110200010' group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) DIV 3600;
```

the output is : 4344 rows in set (0.58 sec)

and the following to get sum fv/0 every 3600 seconds.

```
select sum( JSON_EXTRACT(vals, '$."fv/0"') ) AS val, max(time) AS valtime from pm_data_tab_json where oid='20110200010' group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) DIV 3600;
```

the output is: 4344 rows in set (0.14 sec)

I test many times, the result almost same: "max" takes 4 times longer than "sum", this result make me very puzzled, for "sum" operation need more cpu cycles than "max", but the result is contrary.

I use the mysql profile, the

> show profile

command show that the main difference between the two select commands is "Sending data ".

- the first is "Sending data         | 0.404505"

and

- the second is "Sending data         | 0.132669"

**So My Question is: why max operation on json element is much slower than sum operation.**
(btw, if i put json element(fv/0) as normal float column type, the two operation cost is negligible )

Any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: could be astonishingly trivial like "cache". Have you tried alternating both queries ... and have this result consistently? If the second query is done right after the first, the db probably still has some or most data in cache. Also, when both queries are run at same intervals ... why not combine them?

Comment: @Jakumi, i have test both sql querys many times, the result almost the same: "max" takes 4 times longger than "sum", whatever which query run first;